# logical error( if loops not working as i expected to)

Tags: loops, if-statement

Even after multiple attempts, i can't seem to alter my code so both the conditions may apply. I have only been able to satisfy one at a time.

```
public static String caeserEncrypt(String originalMessage, int shift){
       String finalMessage = " ";  
       int length = originalMessage.length();
       for(int i= 0;i<length;i++){
         char c = originalMessage.charAt(i);
         char shiftedletter = ' ';
         if((int)'a'<=(int)c &&(int)c<='z'||(int)'A'<=(int)c &&(int)c<='Z'){


          if(shiftedletter>'z' || shiftedletter>'Z'){
           shiftedletter = (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i)-(26-shift));
          }
          else{
           shiftedletter = (char)(originalMessage.charAt(i)+shift);
          }
         }
         else{
            shiftedletter = originalMessage.charAt(i);
         }

          finalMessage = finalMessage + shiftedletter;
```

Comment: Both which conditions? (Btw, your code could be formatted a bit better so it is more easily readable: consistent indenting and whitespace for example).

Comment: 1.the character should lie in within the ascii values for lowercase alphabets AND uppercase alphabets only for shift to apply.

Comment: 2.if shifted letter goes beyond 'z' or 'Z', we will cycle through alphabets and apply shift.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with the original code:

- shiftedletter is always `' '` before it is checked to be beyond the alphabet
- if a letter is `> z` it is also `> Z` (and `a` is > `Z`)

Here's a working version:

```
public static String caesarEncrypt( String originalMessage, int shift )
{
   String finalMessage = "";  
   int length = originalMessage.length();

   for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
   {
     char c = originalMessage.charAt( i );
     char d = c;

     if ( 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' || 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z' )
     {
        d += shift;

        if ( Character.isUpperCase( c ) ? d > 'Z' : d > 'z' )
           d -= 26;
     }

    finalMessage += d;
  }

  return finalMessage;
}
```